# How can I use TypeScript compiler through nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a sample code and saved it to a file such as `hello.ts`

After installing nodejs on windows use below command for installing typescript

```
npm install -g typescript
```

How can I compile `hello.ts` with node.js directly?

When I install "TypeScript 1.6 in VS2015" and use tsc.exe don't have any problem but I want to use node.js instead of VS 2015 extension

Please guide me generate .js and .ds through Node.js

Answer (score 1):

> Please guide me generate .js and .ds through Node.js

You have two options:

- Run `tsc.js` as a node script
- Use `typescript` as an npm module

## Run `node tsc.js`

This is the approach taken by some tools e.g [`grunt-ts`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/grunt-ts). You basically just call `spawn` on the current process `process.execPath` passing in the other commands as args (`-d`).

[One sample](https://github.com/TypeStrong/grunt-ts/blob/15b315e018f70e7a3c002f300033e0511f85c891/tasks/modules/compile.ts#L20-L34)

## Run TypeScript as a node module

If you are playing with the typescript compiler API highly recommend [NTypeScript](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ntypescript) See the [Readme for reasons](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ntypescript/blob/master/README.md).

The TypeScript compiler provides a simple function called [`transpile`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ntypescript/blob/3b9746ef42cb6996c553372ad7e81ee480300acc/src/services/services.ts#L1912-L1915) that you can use to get the expected output and then write it out to disk yourself.

PS: I have some docs on the TypeScript compiler internals here : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/compiler/overview.html

Comment: Good answer but 1. it's outdated ("NTypeScript is dead" says the README, but fair enough, this is from 2015) and 2. it should disclose that NTypeScript/byots are your libraries—and possibly add more rationale about why we should use a third-party lib at all here

Answer (score 0):

Run `tsc` in the command line, you'll have the help page. Compiling a script is easy, just [`tsc hello.ts`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Tutorial) in the folder containing your script, you'll get a `hello.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred way to get going is to use `typescript-require`. 
this library basically adds nodejs support for typescript.

your index file should be a javascript file and it will look like this

```
require('typescript-require');
require('./src/main.ts');
```

and `main.ts` is a typescript file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a programatically way from TS/Node to run the equivalent of `tsc` from within a code itself (Note: this uses the [TypeScript Compiler API](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API)):

https://gist.github.com/rnag/0d8fe2e72dc7b48743c13f9ca8837a4c